# How to find Neo4j Query not using index

Tags: neo4j

Find Query not using index on Neo4j

Is there any way to find out query not using index on Neo4j, I really appreciate if any one can guide me on this.

Comment: In Neo4j 3.0.x and up (and even some 2.x versions, not sure which version introduced schema indexes), indexes are used under the hood where possible, without anything explicit in the query for them to be used. So a query for something with and index or without an index looks pretty much the same (usage of the legacy manual index is a separate matter, though). In any case, your question is still rather vague, you haven't given us any insight into your data, labels, properties, or the queries you're attempting to build, or even the purpose as to why you're asking this question.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply, I was wondering is there any way i can log the queries which not using the index, We have configure index for queries but i trying to find a way to log the queries which is not using the index. I cant post quires here since i have 100 of them...

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Neo4j browser, and type in :schema. You should get a list of all the indexes and constraints - on which labels they are added, and on what properties. It will look something like this if no indexes were added:

```
:schema
No indexes
No constraints
```

It will look like this if an index is added on the Person labeled node, on property name

```
Indexes
ON :Person(name) ONLINE  
No constraints
```

In order to check if your indexes are actually used in the query, you should PROFILE the query. If you see more than 2 db hits on retrieving the node by property, and you have 100 nodes, for instance, then it is not using the index.
A reason for this can be the fact that you are querying for a modified string, like so

```
MATCH (n:Person) where reverse(n.name) = "myname"
```